# Error "window.opener.top is null or not an object" for trusted sites WinXP IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, window.opener

I am getting the js error 
"window.opener.top is null or not an object" 
in the IE 8.
For other browser versions looks like we don't have this problem. I added my site to the trusted sites, but this doesn't help.
Hard to understand where the issue is. Looks like this is doesn't related to the protected mode.
Does someone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
tools>Internet Options>security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"
remove the site from Trusted sites list... it is probably already mapped to the same 
security zone as the opener (intranet). 
Select the File>Properties dialog in IE to determine which security zone a page/domain is mapped to.
```

For more info: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/ie/en-us/6c2e23ca-9f85-440b-aec5-3a478528b268/windows-7-ie8-gives-windowopener-as-null)